# How ı build random number not using random library or etc.?

Tags: java, random

I have to generate random numbers in two different places in the project and I do it using the system clock, but I have to get different numbers in both. How can I do that?

Comment: How are you generating random numbers with the clock currently? Why can't you use the built-in random or securerandom or Math.random methods?

Comment: Use the system clock XORed with two different constants to set seeds for two instances of Java's `Random` class, or for your own PRNG implementation if you are trying to avoid `Random`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a loop surrounded by calls to `System.nanoTime()`, then use the least significant bits of their difference as random seed. Once you have, say, 128 bits you can use it as seed for a pseudo random number generator.

Answer (score 0):

There is an article posted in the wiki at java-gaming.org about generating pseudo-random numbers that might be worth perusing. [Pseudo-random number generators](http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/pseudo-random-number-generators/27815/view.html) He shows what he calls an "Old School" method of creating them using a combination of polynomials and modular division. Plus links to other types of PRNGs.

Comment: Might as well just go to [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) (if you're going to go that route).

Comment: I think the thread does include some info on Mersennes. I found another thread at JGO where they are also getting into the weeds. http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/math-random/18426/msg/167189/view.html#msg167189 One of the nice surprises is to see Markus Persson contributing to the discussion. He used to hang out at JGO before MineCraft took off.